# Border around web page?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web page and I am trying to figure out the best way to put a border around the edge that is a image. So, is it best to use 8 divs as in one for each corner and side, or wrap the entire page in a div and use multiple backgrounds with css?

I now it can be done both ways, but which way is better. This would obviously be simpler if I was just using a simple border that is already available through just css, but frankly this is a image border.

Comment: Certainly go for the first technique if you want it to be as cross-browser as possible, as multiple background images is CSS3 which is not supported by IE6 or 7 and I don't think 8 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically using multiple backgrounds is good but the point is some users still stuck with browsers which doesn't support multiple backgrounds, so it depends on your visitors, so it's your call.

Comment: I guess I will go this route, although I could likely go and use tricks such as cs3 pie and vendor specific css